# Копирование объекта

Tags: c#

При попытке скопировать объект b копируется объект a

```
using System;
public interface IClonable{
    object Clone(); 
}
public class Array:IClonable{
    int size;
    int[] ptr = {};
    public object Clone()
    {
        return new Array { size = this.size, ptr = this.ptr };

    }

    public Array(){
        size = 3;
        ptr = new int[size];
        for(int ix=0; ix<size; ix++){
            ptr[ix]=ix;
            Console.WriteLine(ptr[ix]);
        }
    }
    public Array(int size){
        this.size = size;
        ptr = new int[size];
        for(int ix=0; ix<size; ix++){
            ptr[ix]=ix;
            Console.WriteLine(ptr[ix]);
        }
    } 
}
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Array a = new Array();
        Array b = new Array(5);
        Array c = (Array)b.Clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: почему ты решил, что копируется  объект `a`?

Comment: _`ptr = this.ptr`_ - это не клонирование.

Comment: @Grundy, потому что у него вывод только в конструкторах.

Comment: а как клонировать ptr

Comment: в метод clone необходимо хоть что-то передать. У тебя получается что внутри метода clone (size = this.size) - поле сайз равно самому себе. ptr[] - массив, соответственно клонировать его надо, передавая объект с массивом и используя соответствующую команду (клонирование для массива)

Comment: И ещё - рекомендую не использовать в качестве наименования класса  "Array"

Comment: @Garrus_En, зачем в метод Clone что-то передавать? он же клонирует сам объект, у которого этот метод вызывается и этот клон возвращает.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> return new Array { size = this.size, ptr = this.ptr };
> ```

Это же на самом деле

```
var res = new Array();
res.size = this.size;
res.ptr = this.ptr;
return res;
```

А вывод у тебя только внутри конструктора, а конструктор вызван без параметров.

> ```
> ptr = this.ptr
> ```

А это вообще не клонирование - там же массив.

Comment: Почему тогда в объекте "с" все свойства объекта "а"

Comment: потому что в данном случае объекты c и a - ссылки на один и тот же экземпляр объекта в памяти

Comment: @Garrus_En, ты не прав

Answer (score 0):

Если привести именно твой код к рабочему виду, то у меня получилось похоже как у Qwertiy, только с некоторыми изменениями (так чтобы метод Clone не принимал аргументов и возвращал object).

```
using System;
public interface IClonable
{
    object Clone();
}
public class Array : IClonable
{
public int size;
public int[] ptr;

public Array()
{
    this.size = 3;
    ptr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = i;
    }
}

public Array(int size)
{
    this.size = size;

    ptr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = i;
    }
}

public object Clone()
{
    // копирую поэлементно массив
    int[] clone_ptr  = new int[this.size];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
    {
        clone_ptr[i] = this.ptr[i];
    }
    // возвращаю копию
    return new Array() { size = this.size, ptr = clone_ptr};
}

public void Print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ptr.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(ptr[i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
}
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Array a = new Array();
        a.Print();
        Array b = new Array(5);
        b.Print();
        Array c = (Array)b.Clone();
        c.Print();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Здесь нужно сделать некоторые оговорки по поводу того что и почему сделано:

1. size и ptr сделаны public для доступа к ним в этой строке
       return new MyArray() { size = this.size, ptr = clone_ptr};
2. чтобы правильно скопировать массив, нужно сделать это поэлементно или через Array.Copy(), но второй вариант невозможен изза того что твой класс называеться также (да, лучше переименовать его, тогда и Array.Copy() можно юзать и еще много чего);
3. вывод массивов в конструкторе приводит к путанице и проблемам, поэтому лучше сделать метод для вывода, например Print;

Answer (score -1):

Следует сделать так:

```
public class MyArray
{
    int size;
    int[] ptr;

    public MyArray()
    {
        this.size = 3;
        ptr = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ptr[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public MyArray(int size)
    {
        this.size = size;

        ptr = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ptr[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public void myClone(MyArray array)
    {
        ptr = new int[array.size];
        Array.Copy(array.ptr, this.ptr, array.size);
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ptr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(ptr[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

Вызываем в программе так же как вы планировали

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyArray a = new MyArray();
        MyArray b = new MyArray(8);
        Console.WriteLine("Массив А");
        a.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("Массив Б");
        b.Print();

        // Клонируем b в a
        a.myClone(b);

        Console.WriteLine("Массив А после клонирования");
        a.Print();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Вот теперь вызван метод Copy для массива, и всё логически правильно